# Tomcat 7.0.47 keeps throwing errors why?

Tags: tomcat, jdbc, ormlite

Dear Tomcat master out there,

I use tomcat 7.0.47 in my laptop, inside a VM, it runs well at first ... but after sometimes it shutsdown.

I checked on the catalina.yyyy-MM-dd.log, and I found errors on two things:

1. Errors regarding JDBC connection pool, in which I'm using ormlite JdbcPooledConnectionSource
2. Errors regarding access log, this error caused by access log is the most of all, I found around 10 times in a row, than the server seems dead afterwards.

**The error regarding Ormlite jdbc conn pool is:**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1588)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.realClose(Connection.java:4060)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.close(Connection.java:1398)
at com.j256.ormlite.jdbc.JdbcDatabaseConnection.close(JdbcDatabaseConnection.java:144)
at com.j256.ormlite.jdbc.JdbcPooledConnectionSource.closeConnection(JdbcPooledConnectionSource.java:330)
at com.j256.ormlite.jdbc.JdbcPooledConnectionSource.closeConnectionQuietly(JdbcPooledConnectionSource.java:341)
at com.j256.ormlite.jdbc.JdbcPooledConnectionSource$ConnectionTester.testConnections(JdbcPooledConnectionSource.java:494)
at com.j256.ormlite.jdbc.JdbcPooledConnectionSource$ConnectionTester.run(JdbcPooledConnectionSource.java:439)
```

**While error regarding access log is like this:**

```
WARNING: Exception while attempting to add an entry to the access log java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.log(CoyoteAdapter.java:512)
at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:191)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

It seems that there are some kind of memory leak or something ... but the Tomcat suddenly drop.

Can anybody help?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: I guess I will move on with RESIN ...

Comment: Can you verify with jconsole that you have a memory leak?  The exceptions don't seem to be saying so.  Can you look at the specific exceptions in the `WebappClassLoader` to see what it is trying to say?

Comment: I found a warning on memory leak, when I shutdown the tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, frankly speaking I gave up on my old codings ...
What I did to fix this are:

1. I'm not using 3rd party DB Connection pool lib anymore, I changed it to use built-in Tomcat db connection pool and access it from my codes using JNDI lookup. (I hope this way, tomcat will handle it better) --> I followed my Tomcat db pool config according to this [**site**](http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/tomcat-jdbc-connection-pool-configuration-for-production-and-development/), thanks to that guy :).
2. I commented the access logging in **server.xml**, so tomcat will no longer log any access (its not recommended by some postings, but what the heck!), I use Apache log instead, since I'm using Apache as my reverse proxy to my java web app in tomcat.

But I'm still open to any suggestion.

Thanks
Bromo